# can we set custom adapter to android fragment(My requirement Strictly needs only custom Adapter not array Adapter)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

Iam trying display some data from web services in a Fragment,for this i need to use custom adapter because i am using pojo class to set and get data.

iam new to android and i know custom adapter to activity but i need for fragment.

My requirement is to display like the single item xml file singleitem.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/txt3"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/txt4"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

which i want to display some data which contains 4 different fields in a listview row.

And i want custom adapter to setAdpater() to my Listview.

Is there any procedure to add custom adapter to Fragment or  with in array adapter can i assign the values by using pojo class.Suggest me.

this is the custom adapter class iam using in Activity
can anyone suggest the possible changes for the adapter class

```
public class EnrollmentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
MainActivity activity;
ArrayList<EnrollmentData> data;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public EnrollmentAdapter(MainActivity activity,ArrayList<EnrollmentData> data)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_enrollmentsingleitem,null);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    TextView tv3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    TextView tv4 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt4);
    tv1.setText(data.get(i).getReg_num());
    tv2.setText(data.get(i).getW_list_on());
    tv3.setText(data.get(i).getW_list_priority());
    tv4.setText(data.get(i).getElements_to_complete());
    return view;
}
```

Comment: "can we set custom adapter to android fragment" -- a fragment, like an activity, does not use an `Adapter` directly. An `AdapterView`, such as a `ListView`, uses an `Adapter`. That `AdapterView` can be managed by either an activity or a fragment. Why would `EnrollmentAdapter` need to change, just because your `ListView` is shown in a fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve my above question by using array adapter also meet my requirements

```
public class CourseCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CourseCompletedInnerData> {
private Context context;
int  layout;
ArrayList<CourseCompletedInnerData> data;
public CourseCompleteAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<CourseCompletedInnerData> data) {
    super(context, layout,data);
    this.data = data;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.context =context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    }
    TextView tvScore = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtcoursesinnerscore);
    TextView tvActionstatus = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtcoursesinneractionstatus);
    tvScore.setText(data.get(position).getScore());
    tvActionstatus.setText(data.get(position).getAction_status());
     return convertView;
}
```

}